# Is "divide into" in this sentence equivalent to "be divided by"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, verbs

> When the beats **divide into** twos, the music is said to be in simple time;

Source: The AB Guide to Music Theory, page 19, in the last paragraph

But I don't understand why is the 3/4 time signature also in simple time, since 3 can not be divided by two.

In [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/58265/103221) it says that:

> *idiomatic alternative...*
>   divide 2 into 4, giving the answer 2

And in [this definition](https://www.google.com/search?q=divide&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8):

> (of a number) be contained in a number without a remainder.
>   "3 divides into 15"

Then I guess that "divide 2 into 4 without a remainder" amounts to "2 divides into 4", and hence "the beats divide into twos" means "**twos can be divided by the beats with no remainder**". But does that statement make sense?

Comment: 3/4 time has 3 beats in a bar, but *2 quavers in a beat*

Answer (score 1):

**You are misunderstanding the use of "divide into" in the music example.**

In common 4/4 time, the beats can be divided into 2. This is not because 4 is divisible by 2, but because *each individual beat* has two quavers in it. In 3/4 this is the same. *Each beat* has 2 quavers in it.

In compound time, the beats cannot be divided into 2. 6/8, for example, has 2 beats, each beat with 3 quavers.

The sentence is saying that the *individual beats* can be divided into two, not *the number of beats in a bar*.

---

The meaning of "divide into" in this sentence is the same, you just applied it to the wrong thing.

Comment: Could you please paraphrase "When the beats divide into twos" using "divided by"?

Comment: "When every beat in a bar can be divided by two(quavers)"?

Comment: Then is "when the beats divide into twos" equivalent to "when one beat can be divided by two(quavers)", and hence "when one beat divides into two"?

Comment: And hence "divide into" is the same as "be divided into"? In this scenario?

Comment: @Lerner Correct. Simple time is simple because each beat has two subdivisions (beats can be divided into 2). Compound time is compound because each beat has three.